# Handling axios errors and responses (vue) works only with one error. How to notify multiple errors?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, prototype, response

I have a Vue application which communicates with API (using axios requests) and return error(s).
It works fine if I get only one error, for example when response is like this: `{"error":"passwords.token"}`

When i'm getting cumulated errors like this:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.",
 "errors":{
   "password":["The password confirmation does not match."]}
}
```

Here is my code of my Vue component and method resetPassword()

```
methods: {
        resetPassword () {
            this.$vs.loading()

            const payload = {
                userDetails: {
                    email: this.email,
                    password: this.password,
                    password_confirmation: this.password_confirmation,
                    token: this.token
                }
            }

            this.$store.dispatch('auth/resetPassword', payload)
                .then((response) => {
                    this.$vs.loading.close()
                    this.$vs.notify({
                        time: 10000,
                        title: 'Authentication Success',
                        text: response.message.data.message,
                        iconPack: 'feather',
                        icon: 'icon-success-circle',
                        color: 'success'
                    })
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.$vs.loading.close()
                    this.$vs.notify({
                        time: 6000,
                        title: 'Authentication Error',
                        text: error.message,
                        iconPack: 'feather',
                        icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
                        color: 'danger'
                    })
                })
        },
    },
```

Comment: Did you mean that when you have more than one error the message shown in notify is `The given data was invalid.`?,

Comment: No, actually error is [object Object] and error.message returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the issue is that when you have more than one error, you only see one message `The given data was invalid`.

Here is why:

Whit this syntax:

```
"errors":{
  "password":["The password confirmation does not match."]}
}
```

You are not using the error.message properly, as you use in the notify call:

```
this.$vs.notify({
  time: 6000,
  title: 'Authentication Error',
  text: error.message,
  iconPack: 'feather',
  icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
  color: 'danger'
})
```

What you can do is return the same array of errors always, even if you have one error or ten errors:

```
"errors": [
  {
    type: "password",
    message: "Wrong password"
  },
  {
    type: "user",
    message: "Wrong user"
  },
  // As recommendation, notify only "Authentication error", instead the specific field
  {
    type: "Authentication error",
    message: "Wrong credentials"
  },
]
```

And you can notify this way:

```
.catch(error => { // You return errors inside error object
  const errors = error.errors; // and you can get it here
  // const { errors } = error; // alternative syntax
  for (let err on errors) {
    this.$vs.notify({
      time: 6000,
      title: 'Authentication Error', // You can use err.type
      text: err.message,
      iconPack: 'feather',
      icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
      color: 'danger'
    })
  }
}
```

Alternative for:

```
.catch(error => { // You return errors inside error object
  const errors = error.errors; // and you can get it here
  // const { errors } = error; // alternative syntax
  for (let i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
    this.$vs.notify({
      time: 6000,
      title: 'Authentication Error', // You can use errors[i].type
      text: errors[i].message,
      iconPack: 'feather',
      icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
      color: 'danger'
    })
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the structure in your error response, then check what kind of response are you getting and send the notification:

```
.catch(err => { // You return errors inside error object
  const { error, errors } = err;
  if (error) { // only one error
    this.$vs.notify({
      time: 6000,
      title: 'Authentication Error',
      text: error.message,
      iconPack: 'feather',
      icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
      color: 'danger'
    })
  } else {
    for (let errorType of errors) { // more than one error
      this.$vs.notify({
        time: 6000,
        title: 'Authentication Error',
        text: errors[errorType][0],
        iconPack: 'feather',
        icon: 'icon-alert-circle',
        color: 'danger'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

It's not a good idea this approach, but if you want to use it, then it's fine.

Comment: Thank you for your replies (both). One question  about "for". I catch errors using .catch(error => { }. Where should I put "for (let error on errors) ?

Comment: Trying to put "for" loop as you wrote - i'm getting SyntaxError - Unexpected token, expected ";". Looks like "on" is illegal.

Comment: Remember to update your api to return an array of objects, each object with type and message, like in the example, can you paste the returned error from your api?

Comment: So far when I have only one error, I get following response: {"error":"passwords.user"} and it works fine. When validator returns more than one error, my response looks like this: {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"password":["The password confirmation does not match."]}}. Unfortunately (let err on errors) returns syntax error ("on" is illegal). Second example for (let i=0...) returns error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined.

Comment: Are you able to change the errors that you get from the API?, if you can't, I can help you updating the code and doing something else, otherwise, I recommend you to update the api response.

Answer (score 0):

Dont have different keys because one time it will be one error and some other time it will be two or three. for example dont do: 
1 error: { error: "error message" }
2 errors: { errors: {"error_1": "error message 1"} }
thats as you see is very compicated. just put a syndax in there and after follow it even if its one or two or so. for example you can make it like

```
errors: [
   {type: "wrong_user_name_or_password", message: "Wrong user name or password"}
]
```

then you can prettify your notify function to take loop all of your errors and show them like

Cannot login. reasons:

errors.message

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will unify keys but to be honest I have no idea how to do a loop. I've tried forEach, for(let...). forEach is not working with [object Object], and for (let errors on error) i'm getting syntax error on "on".

Comment: If you keep it like object then foreach to work need an array you must do Object.keys(yourObjectHere).foreach(keyName =>{
  // keyName will be something like the password you put there as key so if you want to enter the message you have to do yourObjectHere[keyName]
})

Answer (score 0):

For API responses I use sendResetFailedResponse method from original Laravel's ResetsPassword.php, and it looks like:

```
protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'email' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('email'))
                    ->withErrors(['email' => trans($response)]);
    }
```

I've overridden this method in my API/ResetPasswordController.php as follow:

```
use ResetsPasswords;

    protected function sendResetResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        $email = $request['email'];
        return response(['message' => $response]);
    }

    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        return response(['error' => $response],422);
    }
```

And ValidationException.php

```
public static function withMessages(array $messages)
{
    return new static(tap(ValidatorFacade::make([], []), function ($validator) use ($messages) {
        foreach ($messages as $key => $value) {
            foreach (Arr::wrap($value) as $message) {
                $validator->errors()->add($key, $message);
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

API's response example (from Postman):

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "token": [
            "The token field is required."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email field is required."
        ],
        "password": [
            "The password field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```